# Proxy https requests and add a query param

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-rewrite, https, proxy

I am not very experienced with Apache. What I want to do is to have a proxy server that I can use on a browser or with mobile clients to intercept HTTPS traffic to specific domains, then add a query param to the corresponding request and forward it.

With Apache I got it working using mod_rewrite for HTTP requests like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !PARAM
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?PARAM=SOME_FIXED_VALUE [P,QSA]
```

But not for https. I guess its related to the encryption and me changing the request.

I own the SSL certificate - so I could use it to offload the traffic if necessary for the change.

I am somehow stuck on how to do it though and if this is possible. Any help would be appreciated. If its not possible with Apache, I am also open for other possibilities.

Comment: Is this only for 1 site (your own)?  If so, can you set up a reverse proxy instead.  then it can use your cert, take the request, add the query param, and pass the request on to your actual server.  Apache should be able to do this. What platform are you on?